# Magento API V2 sales orders list not working

Tags: web-services, magento

I am using the API V2 "`salesOrderList`" for receiving a list of all the Orders which have been placed in Magento. But the SOAP Response is showing me an error as:-

```
Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "1" already exist
```

I am using Magento Enterprise version 1.9.0.0.

After looking into the SQL & searching the database, I found that for each Order, the SQL is providing 4 records for the same Order Entity ID; with the difference being only in the name fields of the billing & shipping area. Also the query is doing two Left Joins with the same database table "`sales_flat_order_address`" by using two different aliases (one for billing & another for shipping). From my understanding, this should have worked.

What is happening, and what can be done to recover from this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly, Magento is creating an order collection for you and attempting to load all the records. This collection has a rule that only allows it to create one order object for each ID, so when your additional object is loaded an exception is thrown.

The left joins could be the issue, but it's hard to say off the bat. Could you post a little detail on how you are making the API call? An incorrect join can often have this problem.

---

EDIT:

If you're using the default code, my first guess would be that there are erroneous records in the database, or that this is an upgraded Magento system which had a bad upgrade in the past. Try this on a clean copy of your EE version pointing to the same database. If the same problem occurs, you may need to spelunk in the database looking for the reason for the problematic data load. Since you already have the query, you may want to separate out parts of the query to see if some subquery is returning too much data.

Comment: I'm using the default Magento code, but in that case also, I'm getting the same error. You can look at this Class "`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api_V2`" for this method "`items`". My only concern is how the Magento's default code is not working & what should I do to make this working? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: After going through your mentioned steps, I found that the result of SQL is 4 records, for each order. The reason for this is partly because of the fact that the billing address & the shipping address are different. However, many previous encounters with such type of orders still work with only one record for each Order. Still any more ideas?

Comment: If the billing and shipping addresses are kept as different aliases, there's no reason why that should cause it to mux each record. Can you edit the question with the SQL that gets generated and an example of a single order (all four rows) that gets returned?

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable suggestions. After reinstalling the whole Magento Enterprise staging, this started working correctly, without any such issues. (whew)