# Magento API 'Exception' with message 'Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "X" already exist'

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to get a list of orders using the Magento REST API.

The REST request we use is pretty basic: http://www.example.com/api/rest/orders

The response shows the next error:

```
{
  "messages": {
    "error": [
      {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id \"54\" already exist"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Checking my exception log to see what's going on and got the next backtrace of the error:

```
2015-09-10T21:54:59+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Exception' with message 'Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "54" already exist' in /path/to/site/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php:373
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/site/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(576): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
#1 /path/to/site/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(301): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#2 /path/to/site/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Api2/Order.php(302): Varien_Data_Collection->getItems()
#3 /path/to/site/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Resource.php(245): Mage_Sales_Model_Api2_Order->_retrieveCollection()
#4 /path/to/site/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Dispatcher.php(74): Mage_Api2_Model_Resource->dispatch()
#5 /path/to/site/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php(239): Mage_Api2_Model_Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request), Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Response))
#6 /path/to/site/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php(107): Mage_Api2_Model_Server->_dispatch(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request), Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Response), Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Auth_User_Admin))
#7 /path/to/site/api.php(67): Mage_Api2_Model_Server->run()
#8 {main}
```

I modified the file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Api2/Order.php (function _retrieveCollection) and added a line to print some info on the logs:

```
Mage::log($collection->getSelect(),null,'mylog.log');
```

That's part of the output:

```
    [_parts:protected] => Array
        (
            [straightjoin] =>
            [distinct] =>
            [columns] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => main_table
                            [1] => *
                            [2] =>
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => payment_method
                            [1] => method
                            [2] => payment_method
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => gift_message
                            [1] => sender
                            [2] => gift_message_from
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => gift_message
                            [1] => recipient
                            [2] => gift_message_to
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => gift_message
                            [1] => message
                            [2] => gift_message_body
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => order_tax
                            [1] => title
                            [2] => tax_name
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => order_tax
                            [1] => percent
                            [2] => tax_rate
                        )

                )

            [union] => Array
                (
                )

            [from] => Array
                (
                    [main_table] => Array
                        (
                            [joinType] => from
                            [schema] =>
                            [tableName] => sales_flat_order
                            [joinCondition] =>
                        )

                    [payment_method] => Array
                        (
                            [joinType] => left join
                            [schema] =>
                            [tableName] => sales_flat_order_payment
                            [joinCondition] => main_table.entity_id = payment_method.parent_id
                        )

                    [gift_message] => Array
                        (
                            [joinType] => left join
                            [schema] =>
                            [tableName] => gift_message
                            [joinCondition] => main_table.gift_message_id = gift_message.gift_message_id
                        )

                    [order_tax] => Array
                        (
                            [joinType] => left join
                            [schema] =>
                            [tableName] => sales_order_tax
                            [joinCondition] => main_table.entity_id = order_tax.order_id
                        )

                )

            [where] => Array
                (
                )

            [group] => Array
                (
                )

            [having] => Array
                (
                )

            [order] => Array
                (
                )

            [limitcount] =>
            [limitoffset] =>
            [forupdate] =>
        )

    [_tableCols:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

If I understood correctly that means that the SQL statement was something like:

```
SELECT 
    main_table.*,
    payment_method.method AS method,
    gift_message.sender AS gift_message_from,
    gift_message.recipient AS gift_message_to,
    gift_message.message AS gift_message_body,
    order_tax.title AS tax_name,
    order_tax.percent AS tax_rate
 FROM
 sales_flat_order AS main_table LEFT JOIN
 sales_flat_order_payment AS payment_method ON main_table.entity_id = payment_method.parent_id LEFT JOIN
 gift_message ON main_table.gift_message_id = gift_message.gift_message_id LEFT JOIN
 sales_order_tax AS order_tax ON main_table.entity_id = order_tax.order_id
```

After manually running the previous query, it came up with more than one row with the same entity_id (sales_flat_order). These 'duplicated' entity_id rows seem to be the problem later on when using `Varien_Data_Collection->addItem`

The part of the query that is making the two rows with same entity_id to be on the resultset is the LEFT JOIN sales_order_tax. That table contains can contain N rows per each order placed, since every row contains a different tax rule applied.

> For example in Canada we collect two different Tax Rules combined for
>   some areas. In British Columbia we collect GST 5% (country specific)
>   plus PST 7% (province specific).

Am I missing something obvious here, or did I run into a bug?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks for reading!

P.S. My issue is very close to the one described in here: [Magento API V2 Sales Orders List Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013948/magento-api-v2-sales-orders-list-not-working)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a while playing around I think I found a solution, so I'm posting it here for future references.

**Solution**

We need to modify the query of the collection, to group by sales_flat_order.entity_id before it starts iterating the items in Mage_Sales_Model_Api2_Order::_retrieveCollection.

Since modifying core files it's not a good practice we can make a copy of the core class to the local code pool and modify it as desired. Magento will use the class under the local folder to override the core class.

1. Copy app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Api2/Order.php to app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Api2/Order.php
2. Modify the file under the local code pool folder (app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Api2)
3. Look for the function _retrieveCollection (around line 288 in Magento 1.9.2)
4. After the line `$this->_addTaxInfo($collection);` you should add: 
   `$collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');`

**Cons**

If we are updating Magento we want to compare our current version of the Mage_Sales_Model_Api2_Order class with the new version, and if we find differences we shall repeat the process of making a copy of the core file under the local code pool folder and perform the edition again.

Comment: This solution may cause problems when u use paging. The limit still works, but the pagenumber does not, so it is always returning the same dataset. So when using limit and pagenumber, the limit works, but the pagenumber doesn't.